# mock object in unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, dart

This may be overasked, but I just couldn't grasp what is it for, and when/why I use it. Since I'm learning `dart`, I'm gonna give my example in `dart` and I hope I'll get answer in `dart` too. Also I'm new with unit testing.

Imagine I have 3 class, a `Person`, a `Translator`, a `Db`. `Person` can do query, `Translator` translates the query given by `Person`, so `Db` can process it.

```dart
class Person {
  query(String args, Translator translator) => 
      translator.query(args);
}

class Translator {
  Db db;

  Translator(this.db);

  query(args) => db.query(args); // assuming Translator knows what the db type is
}

class Db {
  String type;

  Db(this.type);

  query(args) => // query with args, return the result;
}
```

Now I want to test if the `Translator` is doing good:

```dart
void main() {
  var mongoDB = new Db('mongodb'),
      translator = new Translator(mongoDB),
      person = new Person(),
      result = person.query('give me 1 Person named Andy', translator); // get the result

  expect(result['name'], equals('Andy'));
}
```

From what I have read, mocking is used if I have a case like above, `Translator`'s dependency with `Db` and a `Db` io.

Which class should I mock, `Translator` or `Db` ?

In what way/how do I mock the class?

What benefit I get from mocking?

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of a mocking framework is to simulate the integration to external systems in your code. If you don't mock the dependencies you are writing an integration test, and not a unit test. A big benefit of this is that you don't have dependencies on existing data in the external systems (data in the DB etc). There is also a performance benefit since you don't have to make potentially slow calls to external systems.